# Android fragment animations not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Ladies and Gentlemen,

I am learning to develop for android and I am a bit stuck with fragment animations.

I have an activity with a button at the top. Under the button I programmatically add a blue fragment when the activity is created. At the click of the button I want the blue fragment to disappear, and a green one to appear.

It works fine without animations ( left it commented out at the top of the method ).

Then I try to use the replace() method, and remove + add methods after that. Neither behave as I would expect...

replace: I click the button and the blue fragment slides out. The green fragment is already present under the blue one. Then the green disappears and slides in as expected.

remove / add: the blue fragment disappears without animation, the green fragment is already present, then disappears and slides in

Could someone please give me a hand fixing both ways? I have done a lot of googling, but can't work out what the issue is.

Also, a couple of words explaining where wrong, so that I don't repeat the same mistake again in the future.

Here is the code of the main activity:

```
package com.example.zz0011_detach_attach_fragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();       

        ft.add(R.id.blueFragmentPlaceholder, new BlueFragment(), "blueFragmentTag" );

        ft.commit();
    }

    public void buttonClicked ( View view )
    {
        // ==============================================================================
        // ================================================================= NO ANIMATION

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------- WORKS FINE

        // ==============================================================================       

        // FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();    

        // ft.remove(fm.findFragmentByTag("blueFragmentTag"));
        // ft.add(R.id.greenFragmentPlaceholder, new GreenFragment(), "greenFragmentTag" ); 

        // ft.commit();

        // ==============================================================================
        // ================================================================== REPLACEMENT

        // ----------------------------------------------------- BLUE FRAGMENT SLIDES OUT 
        // ----- GREEN FRAGMENT IS ALREADY PRESENT UNDERNEATH, DISAPPEARS, SLIDES BACK IN 

        // ==============================================================================       
        //       getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations 
        //       (
        //              R.animator.slide_in, R.animator.slide_out, R.animator.slide_out, R.animator.slide_in 
        //          ).replace 
        //          ( 
        //              getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag ( "blueFragmentTag" ).getId(), new GreenFragment() 
        //          ).commit();     


        // ==============================================================================
        // ========================================================= REMOVAL AND ADDITION

        // --------------------------------- BLUE FRAGMENT DISAPPEARS  WITHOUT  ANIMATION
        // ----- GREEN FRAGMENT IS ALREADY PRESENT UNDERNEATH, DISAPPEARS, SLIDES BACK IN 

        // ==============================================================================       

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations ( R.animator.slide_out, 0 ).
        remove ( getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag ( "blueFragmentTag" ) ).commit();       

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations ( R.animator.slide_in, 0 ).
        add(R.id.greenFragmentPlaceholder, new GreenFragment(), "greenFragmentTag" ).commit();
    }
}
```

This is the android_main XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.zz0011_detach_attach_fragment.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/clicableButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
    android:text="@string/click_me"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/blueFragmentPlaceholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/clicableButton" 
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    >
</FrameLayout>
```

---- EDIT

I have found where the problem was, it was in another file which I now add to the original post

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="-1000"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:startOffset="300" />

</set>
```

The reason why the green fragment was showing was the startOffset value. It shouldn't be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use `replace` always and skip the `add` at the beginning. Also, you are referring to different tags, use the same tag for maintaining `Fragments` in the same stack. Use this method below for replacing fragments, where `R.id.content` is the content `(FrameLayout)` where `Fragments` will be displayed, use same for all of them. I added for you `clearBackStack` so you can choose when you want to display a `Fragment` as root level.

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean clearBackStack){
        if (clearBackStack) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        } 
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment, "current");
        if (!clearBackStack) {
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

Comment: Carnal, thank you for your help. I changed my code accordingly and I have just found out about the stack - as I said, just started... However the same issue I had before still persists: original fragment slides out,, second one is already there, then disappears and slides back in. Any idea on why this happens?

Comment: Sorry, Carnal I am still trying to figure out how to post replies in a proper frame and not these tiny boxes! Enter key submitted my second post instead of new line... The bit I added, for the animation, is the following: ft.setCustomAnimations (R.animator.slide_in, R.animator.slide_out, R.animator.slide_out, R.animator.slide_in );

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean by "tiny boxes"? Yes, you can set customAnimations like you described and it should work.

Comment: I can only add comments after your original answer, like this one here, and not a proper clearer post like my first, or your first answer. The code for the animation I added doesn't work, as per my original post. The blue box slides out, the green is already present straight away, then disappears and slides back in. Is there a way not to have the green box present straight away, but only slide in after the blue one has disappeared?

Comment: Ok, you post replies like a comment like you're doing right now. If my answer helped, you should accept it. And if you need further help, create another question.

Comment: Yes. if you use my method, in your onCreate set clearBackStack = true, then when you want to push a new fragment, set it to false.

Comment: The original issue still persists, I have tried setting the clearBackStack first to true and then false. I don't know why, but the green ( second ) fragment is already there when the blue ( first ) fragment slides out. Not sure why, but if there's a way not to have it there straight away, but only slide in at the end, it would be great. But I am only doing this as exercise to learn my way around android, so if there is no solution to it, it's not a big deal

Comment: Of course it has a solution, maybe you declare the fragment from start in XML? Post your XML file.

Comment: The behavior you will get. At start, the blue is there. Then your push the green, blue slides out left and green slide in from right. When you hit back, green slides out to the right and blue slides in from the left.

Comment: It all works as expected, except that when the blue fragment slides out, the green is *already* visible there straight away. So, the blue slides out, the green is already present there even if it shouldn't be, then the green disappears, then the green slides in. I would like not to see the green one until the end when it is supposed to slide in

Comment: I have just realised what the problem was - it was in the fragment xml file. startOffset was set to 300, I didn't know what it was and just kept it from a similar example I took it from. Removing that value makes everything work fine. Carnal, Apologies for not realising it earlier, but, as I said, I am extremely new to android

Comment: Sure, no need to apologies. That's why we are here, to help :)
Good luck with your future projects.